# php inputting multiple records by id into object for output later on

Tags: php, object, foreach

This is a simple batch of code, I have tried things such as `$Projects = (Object) $array` and others that involve converting arrays to objects, and objects to arrays. My issue always stays the same where when the `$_GET` is populated all records from the `PE` table are sent into the `ProjectEmployees` variable. From there, I use a `foreach` to go through each one and take each of the `Project IDs` and take the corresponding project and add it to the `Projects object`. This object is then sent to a form where all the data is read out and displayed.

My issue is that within the foreach loop the `$Projects` object gets overwritten and only ever outputs 1 record, even though I know there should be 2, it is also the second record so I know it is overwriting not just skipping. I know it is reaching that point as the find function is a `select * where the EmployeeID = ID` which I have tested within the database itself so I know it should work.

```
public function list() {
    if (isset($_GET['employee'])){
        $ProjectEmployees = $this->ProjectEmployeesTable->find('EmployeeID', $_GET['employee']);

        foreach($ProjectEmployees as $ProjectEmploy){
            $Projects = $this->projectsTable->find('ProjectID', $ProjectEmploy->ProjectID);
        }
}
```

So my question is whether there is any way to correctly iterate the records I want from the `ProjectsTable` ,according to the project `IDs` within the `ProjectEmployees` variable, into `Projects`.

Comment: Each time through the loop you're just setting `$Projects` to reference to the _current_ `$Project`.  It looks/sounds like you want to be _pushing_ `$Project` on to `$Projects` where `$Projects` is an _array_.

Comment: `array_push($Projects, $Project);`? As I understood, you need this...

Comment: @PatrickQ my apologies, that line was one of my tests I removed it now

Comment: @Danielius I will give that a try

Comment: Now `$Projects` doesn't exist in your code at all and your statement "My issue is that within the foreach loop the $Projects object gets overwritten..." is inaccurate and irrelevant to your code.  Please both show and describe the code that you are _actually using_ so that we are well-equipped to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to store all project in array like: **$Projects=array();**
2. In **foreach** loop You need to push all project in that
   **$Projects** array.
3. Then you need to return this array like: **return $Projects;**.
4. Getting the result you need to call that method.

Calling this method like this:

```
$obj = new YourClass();
$Projects = $obj->list();

var_dump($Projects);
```

Your class:

```
class YourClass(){

    public function list() {
        $Projects=array();
        if (isset($_GET['employee'])){
            $ProjectEmployees = $this->ProjectEmployeesTable->find('EmployeeID', $_GET['employee']);
            if(count($ProjectEmployees)){ foreach($ProjectEmployees as $ProjectEmploy){
                $Projects[] = $this->projectsTable->find('ProjectID', $ProjectEmploy->ProjectID);
            }}
        }
        return (object) $Projects;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick and I can see I am getting all the records, but I need the output to be an object not an array, is there anyway to do that after getting the data? If not I need to restructure other parts of my code to work with an array instead of an object.

Comment: @David Castellano just replace this: return $Projects; to: return (object) $Projects;

Comment: is there any reason that would not work? I still get the error on my form "Trying to get property 'ProjectID' of non-object" when attempting to read back the data

Comment: may be $ProjectEmployees is not an object. if it's an object then it work.

Answer (score 0):

THIS IS TEMPORARY  ANSWER to @rashid to show him how to transform the array from @DavidCasttelanoo into a object. Its not a answer to the original question. Its a Answer to his comment , where he need a object instead of the array

```
$objectProjects = new $Projects();
foreach ($arrayProjects as $key => $value)
{
    $objectProjects->$key = $value;
}
```

Projects is now a object.

Comment: I marked Rashid as having the solution as he did solve my problem, the issue with the objects vs arrays is something else I need to figure out I think. As your solution still results in the error on the form page I mentioned before: "trying to get property of non object"